# How do I load and read several csvs and then merge afterwards into one file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, merge, glob

I am seriously struggling with the issue of reading multiple csvs from a dir where I have them all listed.

All files I am trying to first read, and then load start with around 15 lines of report info on that file. Trying to eliminate this with skiprows=15, although this only delivers random luck.

Using e.g. glob, I keep getting either "pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file" or "Error reading line XXXX..... saw 23", "Python int too large to covert to C long", "Error: field larger than field limit (131072)". I am trying--on a per month basis--to merge hundreds of files loaded on a per hour load in a share, and then merge each month's loads into Dec, Jan, Feb...and so on. Things worked fine for all months except Dec which is why I am really after some bullit-proof solution able to read any csv file.

I have this:

```
    import glob
    import pandas as pd
    import sys
    import csv
    maxInt = sys.maxsize
    
    while True:
        # decrease the maxInt value by factor 10
        # as long as the OverflowError occurs.
    
        try:
            csv.field_size_limit(maxInt)
            break
        except OverflowError:
            maxInt = int(maxInt/10)
    
    df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, encoding="ISO-8859-1", sep=",", skiprows=7, engine="python") for f in glob.glob('C:\\...._dec*.csv')], ignore_index=True)
    
    df.to_csv("C:\\...\\dec_logons_total_per_some_date.csv", sep=';', index=False)
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../PycharmProjects/FFA_AllFiles/load_multiple_csvs.py", line 51, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, error_bad_lines=False, skiprows=15, header=0, low_memory=False)
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\F...\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\FFA_AllFiles\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\FFA_AllFiles\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 948, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\FFA_AllFiles\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1180, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\FFA_AllFiles\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2010, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 540, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

I tried a lot of attempts, including also skiprows=whatever,

Comment: have you tried loading the offending file on its own? it will be difficult to help without a [mcve]

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, you need me to show you data? Right? My problem is I cannot tell which one of the 520 files loaded for Dec is the offending one...If I misunderstand, please bear with me...;o)

Comment: I think then you need either launch your debugger and step through your code, or write detailed logs to see where its failing.